# Is it possible to install node-sass without downloading from Github during the post install step?

Tags: nexus, node-sass

I'm behind a corporate firewall, proxying the npm repository with Nexus. During the post install step, **node-sass** tries to curl from  https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/linux-x64-48_binding.node but fails due to the firewall. Adding a firewall rule to let the request get through is not an option. If it's possible to also proxy Github through Nexus, that may be an option but I haven't been able to get that configuration working when I've tried.

This is also for a Jenkins build, so having the developer do a `npm rebuild node-sass` after the failed install is not an option. I need the install to work, or the Jenkins build will fail.

Is there any way to install **node-sass** from just the npm registry without also having to download anything from other sources during the post-install step?

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for

in your `.npmrc`

```
sass_binary_site=http://yournexus/wherever/the/binary/lies
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters

Answer (score 4):

You can install the the node-sass using

```
npm install node-sass --sass-binary-site=http://example.com/ or
npm install node-sass --sass-binary-path=<your binary file>
```

the binary file can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases).

Or you can add the flowing line to `.npmrc`

```
# change the /home/wangxiang/linux-x64-72_binding.node to your real path
sass_binary_path=/home/wangxiang/linux-x64-72_binding.node
```

and then:

```
npm install node-sass
```